# Avoiding accessing unauthorized data - architectural level

Tags: .net, design-patterns, database-design, architecture, system-design

I have one SQL Server database that will contain data for multiple customers each customer has admin users to manage his own data related to his employees, I will give each customer a license to use the system to store and manage his business data ( data related to his employees) each employee has an account and has some privileges to do some specific actions and request.

***My question,*** **How to permanently prevent customer admin users to access employees of another customer?** I am asking about the best practices or Ideas related to the system architecture level to avoid this kind of errors, I don't want to leave the decision to the developer because any wrong SQL query will lead to this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major approaches to multitenancy at the database level, with VERY different tradeoffs:

1. tenant by row:  This basically entails putting in a customer-id or tenant-id column into each database table, and ensuring that all queries use this as part of their selection criteria.  If you don't trust the developers (you are in trouble already), you could hide them behind stored procedures (not recommended, just have rules for devs).
2. tenant by schema: Tenant by schema is more secure, but more expensive.  It entails provisioning a new schema for each tenant.  Each tenant gets their own SQL Server connection, and their queries go to their schema.  This has the advantage of absolute prevention of cross-customer reads, but is MUCH more expensive to implement.  It requires executing DDL at run-time when adding a new tenant, and upgrades are MUCH more costly (you have to upgrade dozens/hundreds/thousands of database schemas depending on how many customers you have.  Also, SQL Server will not perform as well when it's dealing with that many small tables.  Statistics/backups/maintenance will be more expensive and more difficult to manage.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that, just mentioning the keyword "multitenancy" Helped me a lot, Thanks :)